# Listing nonvolatile memory devices from terminal

Tags: terminal

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

lists the the SSDs and USB drives from the command line in LINUX systems.

Is there a homebrew package that can be installed to enable `cat /proc/partitions`?

Comment: Try `diskutil list`.

Comment: "macOS isn't Linux." There are many fundamental differences, particularly at the root level, e.g. /dev; and trying to make it so will lead to trouble.

Comment: @IconDaemon  Please consider promoting your comment to an answer for credit

Answer (score 2):

The closest equivalent I can think of is the `diskutil list` command.

This is what it shows on my Mac:

[image]